# sin(A + B) + sin(B + C) + cos(A + C) = 3/2. Find each angle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm given the fact that in $\triangle ABC$,
$\sin(A + B) + \sin(B + C) + \cos(A + C) = \frac{3}{2}$.
I'm asked to get the angles $A, B, C$.
So far what I've done is I've substituted $A+B = 180-C$ and so on in order to get

$\sin(180 - C) + \sin(180 - A) + \cos(A + C) = \frac{3}{2}$.

From here I've used the sin addition identity to get

$\sin(C) + \sin(A) + \cos(A + C) = \frac{3}{2}$

From here I'm stuck. Help!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $120^{\circ}, 30^{\circ}, 30^{\circ}$? I used $\cos(A+C)= -\cos(B)$ and just guessed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let consider

$$f(x,y)=\sin x + \sin y + \cos (x+y)$$

then by

- $f_x=\cos x -\sin(x+y)=0$
- $f_y=\cos y -\sin(x+y)=0$

we obtain as possible solutions (critical points) $x=y=\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 6$, $\frac 5 6\pi$ and only $x=y=\frac \pi 6$ is possible which leads to $A=\frac \pi 6$, $B=\frac {2\pi} 3$, $C=\frac \pi 6$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with multi-dimensional function analysis. Are there any online resources to help me better understand what critical points are and how those other two functions were made?

Comment: Refer for example here https://mathstat.slu.edu/~may/ExcelCalculus/sec-6-3-CriticalPointsExtrema.html

Comment: The idea is that $3/2$ is a maximum for the function, therefore the given solution is unique (a part renaming the angles).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

As $A+B+C=\pi,$

$$\dfrac32=\sin C+\sin A-\cos B$$
$$=2\sin\dfrac{C+A}2\cos\dfrac{C-A}2-\left(2\cos^2\dfrac B2-1\right)$$

$$=2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac{C-A}2-2\cos^2\dfrac B2+1$$

$$\iff2\cos^2\dfrac B2-2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac{C-A}2+\dfrac12=0$$

Use

[$ \cos {A} \cos {B} \cos {C} \leq \frac{1}{8} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952893/cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-leq-frac18)

OR

[Solve equation $\cos (a)\cos(b)\cos(a+b) = -\frac18$ over $0 < a,b < \frac\pi2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959623/solve-equation-cos-a-cosb-cosab-frac18-over-0-a-b-frac-pi2)

Comment: I'm not sure if ou are indicating others way by the given links. From here $2\cos^2\dfrac B2-2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac{C-A}2+\dfrac12=0$ we can conclude that $C-A=0$ and $B=\frac23 \pi$ indeed $p(x)=2x^2-2kx-\frac12$ has minimum equal to $\frac12-\frac{k^2}2$ at $x=\frac k2$ and therefore $p(x)=0\iff k=1$.

Comment: @user, can you please re-phrase query/confusion

Comment: I'm not sure how tha latter identity $2\cos^2\dfrac B2-2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac{C-A}2+\dfrac12=0$ is related to the given links which follow. In the previuos comment I've indicated a way to conclude that $A=C$ but maybe you are indicating a different way.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I was originally confused about why cos(C+A/2) = cos(B/2), but after a little bit of substitution, I was able to get it. Very clever.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(A+B)=\frac{1}{2}$ , $\sin(B+C)=\frac{1}{2}$ , $\cos(A+C)=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore,
$A+B=\frac{\pi}{6}$ , $B+C=\frac{\pi}{6}$ , $A+C=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Therefore after solving we get the value of $A=\frac{\pi}{6}$ , $B=0$ , $C=\frac{\pi}{6}$. This is the required solution.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. You've got the right idea. However, note the angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ are parts of a triangle, so their sum is $\pi$. Thus, as indicated in [Etemon's comment](/questions/4845434/sina-b-sinb-c-cosa-c-3-2-find-each-angle#comment10322175_4845434), and especially [user's answer](/a/4845450), have $A+B=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ an $B+C=\frac{5\pi}{6}$, to then get $B=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ instead.

Comment: Yes I have not noticed that earlier. I am sorry for my mistake